# Playing a data set using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs as front-end framework. I get a data set via a rest get call. 
That contains coordinates in an array. What needs to be done is that array with coordinates should be iterated and should be shown in a map.

[image]

Once the user hits play in the map those coordinates should be displayed one ofter another having at least 1 second of interval.

And when user hits play button, the button it self converts to a pause button it should do what the name intend to do. pause the process. I couldn't achive this kind of behavior using angularjs. Following is the closest that I could come.

```
  var getReplayData = function () {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:4000/replay/asiri/vin/' + from + '/' + to);
    };

    $scope.play = function () {

        from = rangeProperties.getFrom() * 1000;
        to = rangeProperties.getTo() * 1000;


        getReplayData().success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            var waitingTime = 0;
            var gap = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                (function (i) {
                    var element = data[i];

                    var coordinates = new Object();
                    coordinates.latitude = element.LATITUDE;
                    coordinates.longitude = element.LONGITUDE;

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        broadcastData(coordinates);
                    }, waitingTime);

                    if (i + 1 < data.length) {
                        gap = data[i + 1].TIMESTAMP - element.TIMESTAMP;
                        console.log(gap);
                    } else {
                        gap = 0;
                    }

                    waitingTime = waitingTime + gap;
                })(i);
            }


        });
```

$scope.play refers to the play action of the button. I can't figure out how to pause this process. Seems like I might have to keep the references to all timeouts and cancel them. Any idea how to implement this kinda of scenario? I don't exactly need a code segment just an idea how to approach to solve this kinda of problem would be really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems like I might have to keep the references to all timeouts and cancel them.

That would be a good first step.

> I don't exactly need a code segment just an idea how to approach to solve this kinda of problem would be really nice

I would do the following:

- cache the response data as a variable, if possible.
- separate the play and pause functionality, tying them into a *cancelable* callback that you get from using the `$interval` service.
- during playback, treat your coordinates data as a [FIFO (queue)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), dequeuing the item which gets passed to the $interval's promise
- during pause, you simply cancel the $interval promise
- playing again doesn't require any fancy work on the queue as you'll resume the same logic on the first item in the queue when you resume.

Comment: That seems doable. Will try.